# Excel INDIRECT function to another sheet that has a quote

Tags: excel-formula

This may seem like a very simple question, but I don't know the answer. I've searched thoroughly over and over. How can you use the INDIRECT function on a sheet that has a single quote on its sheet name? For example, if your sheet name is Test'Sheet, I can't write the formula properly and always returns #REF.

(Edit: For example, the name of the sheet is located on cell A1 of the active sheet. The name of the sheet is Test'Sheet (or anything that has a quote in it). I used the below formula, but didn't work.

```
=INDIRECT("'"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'",CHAR(34))&"'!A5",TRUE)
```

Of course I tried `=INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!A5",TRUE)` too but that failed as well.

Thanks,
Jonathan Handojo

Comment: Can you please update your question to include the code that isn't working?

Comment: Sorry for that. I just updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a sheet name contains a single quote, you will need to escape the single quote by repeating it, e.g. `'Test''Sheet'!A5`. For your example, the code would look like this:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & SUBSTITUTE(A1, "'", "''") & "'!A5", TRUE)
```

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a double quotation. That did the trick. Thanks!